# Google Font (Pinyon Script) working inconsistent in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a few Google Fonts that is loaded to my web application, and they are working fine in Chrome, Safari and Firefox. In Internet Explorer there are some weird inconsistencies (See image below).

Basically as you can see. At some places the font is not working, but in some places it is working. This is all the same page with the same "load".

You can go to the page of the image yourself if you want at http://bit.ly/1tXRaUc

I'm loading the Font by using the following tag:

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pinyon+Script" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

The different elements have their fonts set in the following way:

1. First text not working has its font set inline with

   ```
   <span style="font-family: Pinyon Script">Pinyon Script</span>
   ```
2. The second element (That is working in the list) have its font set inline with the following code

   ```
   <a href="Pinyon Script" style="font-family: Pinyon Script">Pinyon Script</a>
   ```
3. The third element, that is not working have its font set with the following code

   ```
   <div class="textarea ui-draggable selected" style="position: absolute; z-index: 70; font-family: 'Pinyon Script'; color: rgb(180, 88, 88); font-size: 28px; left: 86.5px; top: 309px;" id="text-1">
       <div class="drag_handle" style="display: block;"><i class="fa fa-arrows"></i></div>
       <div contenteditable="true">Together with their family</div>
   </div>
   ```

So to summarize. All elements have their font set inline. All elements have their font spelled the same way. All elements are on the same page, no iframes or anything like that. Note that it does not matter if the font is written with quote surrounding it or not.

[image]

EDIT: After additional testing I have found the following rule in the Internet Explorer Developmer Tool. This rule is not in any of my .css files but seem to be a rule that Internet Explorer adds automatically in itself, and it seem to be overwriting my inline CSS. I'm not sure how this is possible since inline should overwrite any browser default rules. Any ideas?

The rule I found is:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li...{
    font-family: inherit;
    [... plus a long list of other default rules ...]
}
```

If I remove the font-family: inherit; rule above. It will listen to my inline font-family: Pinyon Script; rule. I can only remove it from the Developer Tool though, since its not in my CSS I'm not sure how I can stop Internet Explorer from overwriting my inline css with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the answer to IE not using the font you wished. For some reason my IE11 on Win7 doesn't exhibit the problem even if set to emulate IE10 or 9. (As you know from talking on IRC about this problem.)

However on the broken button, any editable text section on that page involving a font with a space in the name generates a broken span which doesn't work in any browser. Firebug shows Firefox interpreting that span as follows:

```
<span style="font-family: " headland="" one""="">"Headland One"</span>
```

Fonts selected from the dropdown itself work just fine, spaces or not, so the code doing this must be different for both areas. Tracing the event handling for those boxes leads me to line 104 in editor.js, which looks like this:

```
$('.font-family button').html('<span style="font-family: '+font+'">'+font+'</span> <span class="caret"></span>');
```

If the variable `font` contains quote characters, that will generate broken HTML, which is my guess as to what's happening here. Personally, I would put the quotes inside the HTML string for fonts and strip them from the font name to give you the following starting from line 102:

```
    font = font[0].trim().replace(/['"]/g, '');
    //Set button value to the font
    $('.font-family button').html('<span style="font-family: \''+font+'\'">'+font+'</span> <span class="caret"></span>');
```

This should, in theory, fix the broken button with the least number of changes. It would be smarter though to do the following:

```
    font = font[0].trim().replace(/['"]/g, '');
    //Set button value to the font
    $('.font-family button')
        .html('<span></span> <span class="caret"></span>')
        .children(':first-child')
           .css('font-family', font)
           .text(font);
```

This avoids using string concatenation and inserts the variable content as text, so the browser will handle escaping and the like.

Hope this helps!